# Disable Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, runtime-error

If my application crashes, a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library "Runtime Error!" occurs.

The text of the message is:
This applicaton has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

I know, that I need to solve all these issues, but I imagine that this error did not appear in the past. Is there an option in Visual Studio 2005 to enable/disable such error (handling)?. Instead I expect the application to just crash/exit and offer an Microsoft Windows Error Report.

Comment: I expect that your program has some side affect that is now invalid verse the compiler changes and started given error messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error message appears if an exception is not handled and `unexpected()` is called or if an exception escapes a destructor during stack unwinding and `terminate()` is called. Both lead to `abort()` being called and its `abort()` implementation that shows the message box. This behaviour is by design in VS2k3, VS2k5 and VS2k8. It is really annoying especially in applications meant to run without human intervention (like daily builds for example).

You can workaround this behaviour - use `catch(...)` to catch all exceptions at the top level and set your own `terminate()` handler using `set_terminate()`.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
_set_abort_behavior( 0, _WRITE_ABORT_MSG);
```