# disable to display Run Time Error in Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, runtime-error

I am looking for code or options to disable a run time error. Instead showing that stupid message I just want a crash or to just continue. So in conclusion to do no show that message.

Answer (score 0):

This question (or at least a very similar one) has been answered in [Disable Microsoft Visual C Runtime Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938715/disable-microsoft-visual-c-runtime-error)

The errors need to be handled within your program to stop things going out of your control and the Microsoft dialog being displayed. The answer referred to explains how to capture these errors yourself. One way of implementing crash handling is to capture the minidumps for yourself, using something like [CrashRpt](http://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/) into your software.

Comment: There isn't any method to avoid to show any kind of error. Preferable to be closed and not to show an error.

Comment: Some errors cannot be suppressed (in recent versions of VC), but they only relate to possible security breaches - see the last post on [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/101337/a-proposal-to-make-dr-watson-invocation-configurable).

Comment: but that is only a small subset of the possible errors. Do you see a specific run-time error message each time, or is this a general question ?

Comment: Do you have a try/catch handler at the top level of your program ?

Comment: I have a code, and it gives me an error, and with a Delphi auxilar software I am checking if the process is opened if not it will open it. So it is not a problem. The idea is to create to crash it automatically without showing any kind of staff on the screen.

Comment: I made a try catch in the top level and it gaves the same stupid message. How i can block it to don't show me the messsages?

Comment: Error gived by my software: Assertion failed: result.full () , file d:\opencv....include\ flann\kdtree_index.h, line 523 ... What should I do?

Comment: If you compile the opencv source, and it really doesn't matter if that process stops just get the process to exit rather than asserting if !result.full().  What happens if you build it with a release configuration, so that asserts are not in effect ?  I guess it may fail in an uglier, but different place.